# Android Studio Emulator big border

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

i am unsing the Andriod Emulator from the Android Studio and it worked perfectly before but now it has this big black Border on the Right and Bottom

I tried diffrent Devices (in the AVD manager) and diffrent OS's (in the AVD manager) and i also tried rebooting my Laptop twice

Can anyone help me?

[image: Android Emulator being crazy]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a bug. Click the zoom icon in the emulator toolbar twice and it should be solved.

Comment: Didn't work either

Comment: Any other things to do to solve this?